# SQL Server : delete row trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger, sql-server-2017

I have these 3 tables:

ConstructorEmployee

- `EID` (employee ID)  as primary key and other key.

Project

- `PID` as primary key and other keys.

ProjectConstructorEmployee

- `PID` and `EID` as foreign keys to the other tables.

Each `ConstructorEmployee` can work on several `Projects`. I need to create a trigger that if project has been deleted, I need to delete all `ConstructorEmployee`  that worked **only** on this project. I need to delete them from the `ConstructorEmployee` table.

I'm working on SQL Server 2017.

Comment: I recommend doing it in your code, not depending on `FOREIGN KEYs` to do all the subtle/complex things that you need.  There should be an API for anything complex (like deleting a Project), not just a `DELETE` statement.

Comment: You can define your FK as [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This will take care of deleting the child records when parent record is deleted.

Comment: @Kin they want to delete from `ConstructorEmployee`. There is no FK from that table to `Project`.

Comment: Ok .. I see that. May be a background purge job ran on a daily basis ?

Answer (score 6):

I assume your table schema is similar to next one:

```
CREATE TABLE ConstructorEmployee 
(
    EID int PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Project 
(
    PID int PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE ProjectConstructorEmployee 
(
    PID int, 
    EID int, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_PCE PRIMARY KEY(PID, EID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_P FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES Project (PID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CE FOREIGN KEY (EID) REFERENCES ConstructorEmployee (EID)
);
GO
```

With two FOREIGN KEY on `ProjectConstructorEmployee` table.

Now let me add some data 3 employes and 3 projects, but Employee=1 has worked only on the first Project.

```
INSERT INTO ConstructorEmployee VALUES (1), (2),(3);  
GO

INSERT INTO Project VALUES (1), (2), (3);
GO

-- EID = 1 worked in PID 1 only
INSERT INTO ProjectConstructorEmployee VALUES
(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 3);
GO
```

Next query returns a list of employees that has worked in only one project, in this case PID=1

```
-- Employees working on PID=1 that didn't work in any other project
SELECT EID
FROM   ProjectConstructorEmployee
WHERE  EID IN (SELECT EID FROM ProjectConstructorEmployee WHERE PID=1)
GROUP BY EID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
GO

| EID |
| --: |
|   1 |
```

> I need to create a trigger that...

No, don't use a trigger, let me suggest to use an STORED PROCEDURE, it's always more clear for your and for any further developer. Or if you want to use a trigger, use a BEFORE DELETE trigger that calls this procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteProject(@PID int)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

        DECLARE @employee TABLE (EID int);

        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        -- save a list of employees that only worked in this proejct
        -- due to FOREIGN KEYS you can't delete ConstructorEmployee table
        -- until you have deleted the other both.
        INSERT INTO @employee
        SELECT EID
        FROM   ProjectConstructorEmployee
        WHERE  EID IN (SELECT EID 
                       FROM ProjectConstructorEmployee 
                       WHERE PID = @PID)
        GROUP BY EID
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;                   

        DELETE FROM ProjectConstructorEmployee
        WHERE  PID = @PID;

        DELETE FROM Project
        WHERE  PID = @PID;

        DELETE FROM ConstructorEmployee
        WHERE EID IN (SELECT EID FROM @employee);

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        -- Your error handler

        THROW;

    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Ok, let me try it by deleting projects 1 and 2:

```
EXEC DeleteProject @PID = 1;
EXEC DeleteProject @PID = 2;

SELECT * FROM ConstructorEmployee;
SELECT * FROM Project;
SELECT * FROM ProjectConstructorEmployee;
GO
```

Remaining employees:

```
| EID |
| --: |
|   2 |
|   3 |
```

Projects:

```
| PID |
| --: |
|   3 |
```

and ProjectsEmployees:

```
PID | EID
--: | --:
  3 |   2
  3 |   3
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab208616525bdbec45b2da230f19a331)*

**But...are you sure you want to delete all this information?**

You will lost all the Project's history, employees and projects will disappear of your database. Maybe you could set a flag like Active(Yes/No) a let this information available for whichever want to recover later.